# Unable to send email using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, sendmail, codeigniter-2

I'm unable to send an email through codeigniter. When i tried to echo the error using `echo $this->email->print_debugger();` I got the following error:

```
hello: 250-smtpout17-02.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net 
250-PIPELINING
250 8BITMIME

Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 502 unimplemented (#5.5.1)

from: 250 ok

to: 553 sorry, relaying denied from your location [---] (#5.7.1)

The following SMTP error was encountered: 553 sorry, relaying denied from your location [--] (#5.7.1)

data: 503 RCPT first (#5.5.1)

The following SMTP error was encountered: 503 RCPT first (#5.5.1)
502 unimplemented (#5.5.1)
The following SMTP error was encountered: 502 unimplemented (#5.5.1)
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

I'm not able to  figure out the issue.If you know the reason please help.

Comment: can u show code which u r using.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with SMTP-host. I was providing a wrong smtp host and that's why it was giving me this error.

Comment: Upped this and the original question, as this approach solved the same problem for me. See my answer also for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Hi this code which i used for my project. I am sending from Gmail so change as per your server.

```
function sendMail()
    {
        $config = Array(
      'protocol' => 'smtp',
      'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
      'smtp_port' => 465,
      'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com', // change it to yours
      'smtp_pass' => 'xxx', // change it to yours
      'mailtype' => 'html',
      'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
      'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

            $message = '';
            $this->load->library('email', $config);
          $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
          $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
          $this->email->to('xxx@gmail.com');// change it to yours
          $this->email->subject('Resume from JobsBuddy for your Job posting');
          $this->email->message($message);
          if($this->email->send())
         {
          echo 'Email sent.';
         }
         else
        {
         show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the SMTP-server doesn't allow you to send mails from your IP. Make sure you are using the correct SMTP-server.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue due to several outdated GoDaddy tutorials which provided then confirmed an incorrect host address. I see you were also using GoDaddy's email service (secureserver.net) at the time you had this issue. For anyone else who runs into this problem, the updated information...

```
host = 'smtpout.secureserver.net'
```

..is (currently) detailed here: [link](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6297/outlook-2010-setting-up-email?pc_split_value=3)